# How to import images in MAAS

Tags: boot, disk-image

How to import images for deployment other than ubuntu like VMWare ESXi, Windows, CentOS, RHEL, Ubuntu

Comment: Is [the official documentation](https://maas.io/docs/how-to-import-images) insufficient to answer your question? If it is, could you elaborate on the problem you are facing? 

Comment: there is no official document found on this except the Ubuntu which is inbuilt... i need to know how do we import ISO from our shared location nor from the online page where we download this from their official page like VMware/RHEL/Windows etc...